# How to calculate sensitivity score of Leave One Out Cross Validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I tried to implement leave one group out cross-validation to a classification model. So far, I used this code to do the CV.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneGroupOut

X = X
y = np.array(df.loc[:, df.columns == 'label'])

scores=[]
groups = df["cow_id"].values
logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()

logo.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)

cv=logo.split(X, y, groups)

for train_index, test_index in cv:
    print("Train Index: ", train_index, "\n")
    print("Test Index: ", test_index)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train_index], X[test_index], y[train_index], y[test_index]
    model.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
    scores.append(model.score(X_test, y_test.ravel()))
```

From this code I get accuracy score for each fold. For example if I have 35 groups, I will get 35 accuracy score. My question: how do I obtain the sensitivity score of each fold?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import `recall_score` from `sklearn.metrics` and make use of it as shown below:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneGroupOut
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score

X = X
y = np.array(df.loc[:, df.columns == 'label'])

scores=[]
senstivities = []
groups = df["cow_id"].values
logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()

logo.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)

cv=logo.split(X, y, groups)

for train_index, test_index in cv:
    print("Train Index: ", train_index, "\n")
    print("Test Index: ", test_index)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[train_index], X[test_index], y[train_index], y[test_index]
    model.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    scores.append(model.score(X_test, y_test.ravel()))
    senstivities.append(recall_score(y_test.ravel(), y_pred))
```

Comment: Some error: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [20, 158]

Comment: I don't think I can post in this limited comment section, tho.

Comment: Okay in which line you are getting this error, also what is the dimension of `X_train`, `y_train`,`X_test`, `y_test`? I guess it has something to do with the dimensions of the entities involved.